# what permissions I need for aws ec2 wait

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
-bash-4.2$ aws ec2 wait instance-running $ARG

Waiter InstanceRunning failed: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Now you go to IAM and see a Huge list of permissions, none with **wait** word..., so you look into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/index.html#cli-aws-ec2-wait and find no list of needed permissions...

So: what permissions I need for `aws ec2 wait`?..

Answer (score 5):

purely by trying and failing I found those, that worked for me :

```
{
    "Version": "1980-09-19",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:00000000:instance/i-abababababab"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:ReportInstanceStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume you don't need `start` and `stop` to just `wait`, but I included them, because you use `wait` in pair with either of them...

so in short those are: `DescribeInstances` and `ReportInstanceStatus`

Comment: I don't think you need ReportInstanceStatus. You just need ec2:DescribeInstances.

Comment: I surely tried that and it did not work. please confirm it works for you, if it does - maybe its more complicated then

Comment: I copied the exact same policy as yours without `ec2:DescribeInstances` permission and it works without issues. I had to update the version to 2012-10-17. Can you share the error that you are receiving?

Comment: the one in POST `Waiter InstanceRunning failed: You are not authorized to perform this operation`. but feel free to update the answer or post your own. It surely fails for me without `ReportInstanceStatus`, but I might miss other vars here

Comment: The policy without `ec2:ReportInstanceStatus` worked for me as well

Comment: I needed both `ec2:ReportInstanceStatus` and `ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus`

Answer (score 2):

`WaiterInstanceRunning` needs `ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus` - [ReportInstanceStatus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ReportInstanceStatus.html) reports the status of an instance back to AWS (when an instance has an unexpected status)

Comment: FYI: it also works for "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok ..."

Answer (score 1):

Seems like also "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus" is needed for below command

aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok  --region eu-west-1 --instance-ids